# "if" function gets "control may reach end of non-void function" error in C

Tags: c, if-statement, compiler-errors, conditional-statements, return-value

In this function, I tried to return different `int` values depending on different char* input. But I got the error "control may reach end of non-void function". How can I solve it?

```
// Converts a fraction formatted as X/Y to eighths
int duration(char* fraction)
{
    if (strcmp(fraction, "1/8") == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (strcmp(fraction, "1/4") == 0)
    {
        return 2;
    }
    else if (strcmp(fraction, "3/8") == 0)
    {
        return 3;
    }
    else if (strcmp(fraction, "1/2") == 0)
    {
        return 4;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is returned if `fraction` is none of those?

Comment: what is `string` ?

Comment: @wildplasser — likely `typedef char *string;` from `cs50.h` for the CS50 course.  A guess, but not a wild one.

Comment: @wildplasser, Jonathan made the correct guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must make a default returned value when no condition from those are right 
, try to add return -1 in the end

```
..
else if (strcmp(fraction, "1/2") == 0)
{
    return 4;
}else{
    return -1;
}
}
```